# Check if user voted and if not save vote

Tags: django, django-views

In a simple survey app users should vote only once on a set of questions (survey). I'm able to check if the user voted (either lazy user or authorized user), but only if I prepopulate the fields with test data in the database. I'm also aware that a lazy user could just delete the cookie and would be able to vote again.

I'm not sure how to call `save()` after `form.is_valid()`, because I can't call it twice.

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False) # not in use yet

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.vote
```

views.py

```
@allow_lazy_user
def survey_detail(request, slug, template_name='survey.html'):

    # allows only active surveys to be called otherwise displays HTTP 404
    survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_active=True, slug=slug)

    # checks for user id's in current survey
    voter = [
        v.user.id for v in Vote.objects.filter(survey=survey)
    ]

    # checks if user already voted on survey
    if request.user.id in voter:
            # TODO: use different template or redirect
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    form = ResponseForm(request.POST or None, survey=survey)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        response = form.save(commit=False)
        # gets the current user (lazy or not)
        response.user = request.user
        response.save()

            # HOW DO I SAVE VOTER HERE?

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survey:confirm', args=(slug,)))

    data = {
        'response_form': form, 
        'survey': survey
    }   

    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Another thought I have is to use the boolean field `vote` in the model and check for `True` or `False` in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New solution, since `survey_id` and `user_id` are already in model `Response`:

```
@allow_lazy_user
def survey_detail(request, slug, template_name='itbarometer/survey_detail.html'):

    # allows only active surveys to be called otherwise displays HTTP 404
    survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_active=True, slug=slug)
    categories = [c.name for c in Category.objects.filter(survey=survey)]   
    voter = [v.user.id for v in Response.objects.filter(survey=survey)]

    # checks if survey_id and user_id are already linked
    # if yes, redirect
    if request.user.id in voter:
        return redirect('bereits-abgeschlossen/')

    form = ResponseForm(request.POST or None, survey=survey)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        response = form.save(commit=False)
        # gets the current user (lazy or not)
        response.user = request.user
        response.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survey:confirm', args=(slug,)))

    data = {
        'response_form': form, 
        'survey': survey, 
        'categories': categories
    }   

    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it with

```
@allow_lazy_user
def survey_detail(request, slug, template_name='survey.html'):

    [...]

    form = ResponseForm(request.POST or None, survey=survey)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        response = form.save(commit=False)
        response.user = request.user
        response.save()

            if not request.user.id in voter:
                vote = Vote(user=request.user, survey=survey, vote=True)
                vote.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('survey:confirm', args=(slug,)))

    [...]
```

I'm sure there are better ways, but it works for now.